# Getting this error while creating a new react app. Also tried the uninstall command but it doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

While creating a new react app using npx create-react-app my-app i am getting this error saying "You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App." How can i solve this. Even tried using the uninstall command

[create-react-app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv4iE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, it's recommended you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

You’ll need to have `Node 14.0.0` or a later version on your local development machine (but it’s not required on the server). Its recommend to use the latest LTS version. You can use `nvm (macOS/Linux)` or `nvm-windows` to switch Node versions between different projects.

Moreover Here is the [Documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

You must first update the node version
and run

`npx create-react-app app-name`